# JavaScript library/framework to generate XHTML from parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, xhtml, html-generation

I have a rather complicated question :)

I want to send data in form of json from the server to the client.

There the data shall be used by javascript to generate XHTML from this data.

Now I am looking for a library/framework that helps me generate this XHTML from JSON.

For example a solution could be to have special XHTML "template" files that contain variables which are mapped by name to a javascript method and that method takes the JSON array and fills some parts of the XHTML with the variables in the JSON array.

Example Template File (Pseudocode):

filename: TemplateA.something

```
<html>
Hello my name is %VARIABLE1% !
</html>
```

And the frameworks generates me then a method like that (Pseudocode):

```
generateXHTMLfromTemplate(templatename, data);
```

and it would return XHTML.

For example i would then call it like that (Pseudocode):

```
container.html(generateXHTMLfromTemplate('TemplateA', '{"VARIABLE1" : "Earl"}'));
```

Something like that would be great, the best would be code-completion of these "template" files in eclipse ;)

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

Comment: Others to choose from: [doT](http://olado.github.com/doT/), [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template).

Comment: Wow thanks for the answers, in fact i do work with eclipse and jee (jsf) does any of these libraries have integration with the jee world and/or eclipse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the comment of the post:

> Something like this? [github.com/janl/mustache.js](http://github.com/janl/mustache.js) – Blender
>   yesterday

> Others to choose from: [doT](http://olado.github.com/doT/), [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template). –
>   Pointy yesterday

Answer (score 1):

Despite I will probably be downvoted to oblivion, I will put a very simple alternative.

If you need a very simple functionality then you can use a very simple plugin as `$.fn.loadtemplate`, which is a modification of a previous one of mine [`$.fn.simpletemplate`](https://github.com/aeurielesn/jQuery.fn/tree/master/%24.fn.simpletemplate).

```
$.fn.loadtemplate = function(resource, variables) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: resource,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(html) {
                html = html.replace(/{{(.+)}}/g, function(match, variable) {
                    return variables[variable];
                });
                $self.html(html);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

All the `{{variable}}` tokens will be replace by its appropriate properties of the given object passed to the function.

```
<!-- template.tpl -->
<h1>Hello my name is {{name}}!</h1>
```

```
$("#selector").loadtemplate("template.tpl", {
  name: "World"
});​
```

[**An example fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/XNpbT/)